# Extracting and organising data from text file in python

Tags: python, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, text-files

Python newbie here.

I have a text-file with scraped data from an HTML (via BeautifulSoup's get_text() method) that I want to extract information from. The problem is there are lots of information that I am not interested in and only want to extract the crux.

The text file data example is as follows:

```
EpisodeST02432293
Date collected18/02/2019
Time collected03:15

       Calcium       2.01 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50


EpisodeST02430416
Date collected16/02/2019
Time collected04:00

       Calcium       1.97 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02429201
Date collected15/02/2019
Time collected

       Calcium       1.96 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02424551
Date collected14/02/2019
Time collected00:30

       Calcium       1.93 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02423863
Date collected13/02/2019
Time collected
```

There are numerous other values I also want to organise (Calcium is just an example). I am interested in the **DATE, TIME and VALUE** while disregarding everything else.

**QUESTION**
Which package is the most powerful to use in Python to extract data from a text data?

**EDIT:**

```
DS = namedtuple('DS', 'date time name value')
parsed = list()
idx_date = [i for i, r in enumerate(data) if r.strip().startswith('Date')]

for start, stop in zip(idx_date[:-1], idx_date[1:]):
    chunk = data[start:stop]
    date = time = name = value = None
    for row in chunk:
        if not row: continue
        row = row.strip()
        if row.startswith('Episode'): continue
        if row.startswith('Date'):
            _, date = row.split()
            date = date.replace('collected', '')
        elif row.startswith('Time'):
            _, time = row.split()
            time = time.replace('collected', '')
        else:
            **name, value, _* = row.split()**
    parsed.append(DS(date, time, name, value))

print(parsed)
```

This code gives the error:

> ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack

Comment: _Which package is the most powerful to use in Python to extract data from a text data?_ Asking for library/software recommendations is explicitly off topic. See: [help/on-topic], [ask], [tour].

Comment: if the code I posted gives an error it's virtually guarantueed that the data does not look like you posted. You just need to adjust for those edgecases as you find them.
another thing, you are in your code trying to unpack to the variable name which is in the code initialized to None. Why should that work?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Going to look into those errors.

Answer (score 1):

A small friendly nugde, sure you're a newbie, but if you managed to get this extracted with BeautifulSoup you for sure have the capability to figure out this one on your own.

With that said.

Python is perfect for doing these things without a package, makes it very easy to adapt to whatever you have at hand in terms of data. It does not take long at all to make a custom parser for any specific need, especially if it's text based. Unless you have tenths of million of rows the custom parser approach works and you will Always be able to get the job done.

first your data in a way that just makes it into a list of text rows.

```
data = """
EpisodeST02432293
Date collected18/02/2019
Time collected03:15

       Calcium       2.01 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50


EpisodeST02430416
Date collected16/02/2019
Time collected04:00

       Calcium       1.97 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02429201
Date collected15/02/2019
Time collected

       Calcium       1.96 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02424551
Date collected14/02/2019
Time collected00:30

       Calcium       1.93 L    mmol/L                  2.15 - 2.50
EpisodeST02423863
Date collected13/02/2019
Time collected
"""
```

here's a version that get's the job done.

```
from collections import namedtuple

data = data.splitlines()

DS = namedtuple('DS', 'date time name value')
parsed = list()

idx_date = [i for i, r in enumerate(data) if r.strip().startswith('Date')]

for start, stop in zip(idx_date[:-1], idx_date[1:]):
    chunk = data[start:stop]
    date = time = name = value = None
    for row in chunk:
        if not row: continue
        row = row.strip()
        if row.startswith('Episode'): continue
        if row.startswith('Date'):
            _, date = row.split()
            date = date.replace('collected', '')
        elif row.startswith('Time'):
            _, time = row.split()
            time = time.replace('collected', '')
        else:
            name, value, *_ = row.split()
    parsed.append(DS(date, time, name, value))

print(parsed)
```

and the output:

```
[DS(date='18/02/2019', time='03:15', name='Calcium', value='2.01'),
 DS(date='16/02/2019', time='04:00', name='Calcium', value='1.97'),
 DS(date='15/02/2019', time='', name='Calcium', value='1.96'),
 DS(date='14/02/2019', time='00:30', name='Calcium', value='1.93')]
```

with an approach like this it's also easy to put in float conversion to numbers, making date and time strings into datetime objects etc.

Comment: Thanks. I tried formatting the data by adding it to a dictionary with key=EPISODE, values=date, time, result but I was not getting anywhere. Just want to ask about your code here: name, value, *_ = row.split(). There is a syntax error with the *_?

Comment: the *_ should work on py3.6 and up, which version are you on? not sure what you are trying with the ** and dictionary will be easy to make work.

Comment: Thanks. I tried to BOLD the part where I was getting an error. I quite like your tuple idea as I don't need to change any data, just format, parse and present it. Thank you for your help! I just updated python to 3.7